# ¿Cómo verificar si una función está registrada en el navegador o modificada con JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

Por ejemplo, si alguien con algún polyfill agrega funciones de esta forma:

```
Element.prototype.new_element = function new_element(selector) { //code }
```

o también:

```
Object.new_object = function new_object(target, source) { //code }
```

o quizás se les ocurra modificar alguna existente:

```
var __createElement = document.createElement;
document.createElement = function(tagName) { //code }
```

La pregunta es: **¿Cómo verifico si una función está registrada en el navegador o ha sido modificada con JavaScript?**

Se supone que yo no podría leer el millón de códigos que tiene dicho polyfill para saber qué cosa ha modificado o agregado.

Answer (score 1):

Normalmente con [jquery](/questions/tagged/jquery) lo normal es detectar `domChanged` en caso de que agreguen botones o scripts para modificar componentes vitales sin que te des cuenta y por si las dudas también `DOMSubtreeModified` que es más efectivo, pero no estoy seguro de su soporte en todos los navegadores.

```js
$("body").on("domChanged", function() {
  alert("¡cochino hacker!");
});
$("body").on("DOMSubtreeModified", function() {
  alert("¡cochino hacker!");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1>Modifícame</h1>
```

Estoy seguro que se puede con Javascript Vainilla, pero de momento no tengo el tiempo de investigar cómo ( cuando tenga tiempo complemento la respuesta ). Espero te sea útil.

Comment: quizás el término _"Elemento u Objeto"_ trajo confusión, ya que yo no me refiero a los cambios de estado que sufre el DOM, sino a los **cambios que sufren una función del navegador**, que por cierto; en vanillaJS es así según el ejemplo que mencionas: var insertedNodes = [];
document.addEventListener("DOMSubtreeModified", function(e) {
  insertedNodes.push(e.target);
}, false);
console.log(insertedNodes);

Answer (score 0):

Con muchas funciones propias del navegador, al llamar `toString()`, retornan:

```
console.log(document.createElement.toString()); 
> function createElement() { [native code] }
```

Fácilmente podrías utilizar esto para "detectar" si es una función original o no....

Pero es posible que esta detección también pueda ser *hackeada* por alguien que tiene la capacidad de agregar código a tu pagina/app. Ya sea modificando `toString`, o en ultima instancia, es probable que pueda cambiar la función que hace la detección en si, o evitar que sea invocada.

La mejor solución que tienes es *controlar al 100%* cuales scripts se están cargando. Si no puedes asegurar que código se esta ejecutando, tu pagina/app, sera como un flan.

Pero, si necesitas que el usuario final tenga la posibilidad de cargar scripts propios, probablemente deberías considerar utilizar [Content-Security Policy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_Security_Policy) y alojar los scripts de usuarios en algún `iframe`. De esta manara podrías restringir que es capaz de hacer dicho script y que no.

Comment: _hackear_ esa comprobación es trivial, si alguien quisiera hacerlo:

`var foo = function() { return 1;}
 foo.toString= function() {return "function foo() { [native code] }";}`

De todos modos, como dice rnrneverdies es mejor buscar alternativas que no intentar hacer esta comprobación...

Comment: Usar la solución que mencionan... 
   `function isNative(func) {
  return !('prototype' in func);
}`
 ... es necesario conocer dicha función a verificar. Se supone que, en mi caso; desconociera que funciones u objetos se están agregando al navegador. Por lo tanto, tendría que haber un "guardián" que identifique qué función u objetos se están agregando o modificando en el navegador. O al menos que el GUARDIAN me responda, ¿Qué funciones u objetos se están agregando o modificando desde dicho archivo js que contiene polyfills? O algo más fácil: ¿Si dicho archivo agregó o modificó algo: Si o No?

Comment: @JamesPeter  lo que quieres es una lista de funciones a verificar?

Comment: NO. Lo que desearía saber es cómo puedo detectar si algún archivo.js haya creado o modificado alguna función u objeto. Como en el ejemplo de arriba: `Element.prototype.new_element = function..` Digamos que esto se encuentra en dicho archivo.js, pero tu no sabes cuántos de esos hay ni qué funciones se habrán implementado, características de los polyfills.